# Как в Wordpress поставить рядом два html-кода?

Tags: html, wordpress

Добрый вечер.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне в wordpress поставить рядом два html-кода, так чтобы чат и плеер стояли друг около друга, а не один под вторым?

Вот один код:

```
[hana-code-insert name='videopleer' /]
```

И второй код:

```
[hana-code-insert name='ChatovodChatovod' /]
```

Заранее большое спасибо. Замучалась уже. )))

Comment: @мася2014, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: @мася2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/L6neb0bw/ - display-table

http://jsfiddle.net/s943oqrr/ - inline-block

Также можно использовать float, но не забывайте clearfix.